# Short story about the difficulties of alien/human cooperation

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I **think** I would have read this a few years ago, but I really have no more specific time frame than that, unfortunately. Honestly, it might even have just been a comment in a writing prompt subreddit or something, but I suppose there's no harm in asking.

The story is from the perspective of a member of a non-human species and opens with an explanation of how contact with alien races tends to go: Sure, it's cool that you found aliens, but they're almost always so... well, *alien* that you have absolutely nothing in common. You can't communicate with them and you certainly can't share any kind of scientific advancements or whatever. But every once in a while some race is lucky enough to find intelligent life that's similar enough to itself that they can communicate and collaborate, and that tends to be an incredible development for both societies. And this race is one of the lucky ones to have found a species that they can collaborate with: Humans.

The rest of the story is about the difficulties they have trying to work together. By this point, they've learned each other's languages and are trying to combine their scientific knowledge to build a space ship. The difficulty is that the aliens are extremely focused on the design of the whole ship as a single system, while the humans think of it as a number of smaller systems designed to be modular and fit together. The humans' approach frustrates the aliens because it's inefficient, while the aliens' approach frustrates the humans because a lot of time and money is being spent on a design that, while perhaps slightly more optimal, is just not worth it.

The climax of the story is a human's final attempt to explain their species' way of thinking to the alien. It goes something like this:

"Look, for example, here's something extremely simple. You want to pick something up. You don't look at it and start running calculations to estimate its mass and the amount of force you need to accelerate it to the desired velocity, and then carefully regulate your muscles to provide exactly that amount of force. You just grab it and start pulling."

For the first time, the alien truly understands the human way of thinking, and communicates their own in turn:

"In short, that is exactly what we do."

The story ends with both races understanding each other better and are able to assign jobs to one or the other depending on which approach would be better (I believe that the humans end up designing the ship in their modular fashion but the aliens, able to conceptualize it as a single system, are much better at finding and fixing potential flaws before they happen).

Comment: Humans are having difficulty answering.
They're made out of meat.

Comment: Which does have the theme of so little in common between other races and humans that communication is nearly impossible - because the race does not believe that humans are possible. 

Not positing it as an answer because: 
But it doesn't match the collaboration, luck, or interaction. Rather, human life as the one discoverer describes it is impossible: so impossible that we simply will not consider it.